# How can I incompatible with Gradle 7.0

Tags: android, gradle, build

I bought an android source app.
When I start the project the Gradle can not open it and show this error:

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

CONFIGURE FAILED in 12s
```

How do I resolve this?
Thanks.

Comment: The "deprecated Gradle features ..." message is not an error, just a friendly hint that the build should be upgraded when you have time. If the project doesn't open, there must be other errors.

Comment: Please share sceenshot of error you are facing, as it's not clear from your quetsion